# Mutation of numpy array input to a function

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, mutation

A function I wrote mutated my input variable, a numpy array, and I do not understand why. Let me explain with the following code:

```
def f(array): 
    array = array/2
    return array


def g(array): 
    array[array > 2] = 2
    return array

test_array = numpy.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

f(test_array)

print(test_array) # Returns [[1,2], [3,4]], so test_array is not mutated

g(test_array)

print(test_array) # Returns [[1,2], [2,2]], so test_array is mutated
```

Function f does not mutate test_array, i.e., test_array is unchanged after running f. However function does g mutate test_array.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: That's because a lot of operations return a new array, like division in the first example, while assigning new values for indices mutates the array in place. If you did `array[:] = array / 2` you'd notice `f` mutates your array too. This also has another side effect that you need to be wary of. `array / 2` returns a float array, but assigning those values to an integer array will cast them back to integers. Same with `array[array > 2] = 2.3456`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This stuff still confuses me.

Comment: `var = something` inside a function always breaks the link with the argument `var` variable.  But mutations to an array (or other mutable class like list) don't.  So there are 2 issues, what makes a 'local' variable in a function, and what mutates an object like an array.